# Seeking explanation of structure (Revealing Module Pattern)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

RE: [The Odin Project: Missile Command canvas game exercise.](http://www.theodinproject.com/javascript-and-jquery/building-games-with-canvas)

This project has very few submissions (it's either very new or very difficult), and the two submissions available for reference are from people possessing more experience than I. In the more accessible submission is the following:

```
var missileCommand = (function() {

  //---------
  //hundreds of lines of game logic
  //including 'initialize' and 'setupListeners' methods
  //---------

  return {
    initialize: initialize,
    setupListeners: setupListeners
  };

})();

$( document ).ready( function() {
  missileCommand.initialize();
  missileCommand.setupListeners();
});
```

What is the purpose/meaning/structure behind the return and the subsequent method calls within the $(function)? I'm not sure what's going on, save that removing either set breaks everything.

I know the title isn't very descriptive, but I don't have enough information to do much about it. Will edit when I know what to call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two *completely* separate patterns here.

```
var missileCommand = (function() {

  //---------
  //hundreds of lines of game logic
  //including 'initialize' and 'setupListeners' methods
  //---------

  return {
    initialize: initialize,
    setupListeners: setupListeners
  };

})();
```

This is an implementation of the [*revealing module pattern*](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/). It allows you to create a module (`missileCommand`) which exposes a number of public methods (here, `initialize`, and `setupListeners`). It also allows you to define and store private methods and variables; which will be defined within the area you've commented.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  missileCommand.initialize();
  missileCommand.setupListeners();
});
```

This is a [jQuery ready block](http://api.jquery.com/ready). When the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired, jQuery will run the function provided. Here, that function calls  `missileCommand.initialize()`, then `missileCommand.setupListeners()`.

More often, you'll see the ready block used to attach event handlers to elements;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#some-selector').on('click', function () {
        alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

---

<sup>Note that both of my explanations are  a rather short introduction to each subject. Both links (and further Google-ing of the terms), will give you much more detailed explanations.</sup>

Comment: technically it's the revealing module pattern and an instance of immediate invocation... the missile command setup that is.

Comment: Repeating to ensure a thorough and proper grokking: All methods NOT in the return statement are private. The two within the return statement are public (and all that is public). If I look in the two public functions, I should find calls and handlers for everything else related to the module. The calls within the ready block are simply calls to those public methods. Correct?

Comment: @spectre6000: Spot on :).

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a jQuery object. What it does here is it binds an anonymous function (containing the two function calls, `initialize()` and `setupListeners()`) to the event "ready", which is fired when the document (DOM) is fully loaded.

you can translate that in `jQueryFind(myElement).whenCompletelyLoaded(myFunctionToExecuteOnEvent())` (this is not functional code)

The `return` statement within the `missileCommand` function makes sure than when you do `var myCommands = missileCommand()` it returns an object containing both the values of the `initialize` function and the `setupListeners` function.

Answer (score 0):

In those 100's of lines of code you would for sure find 2 function declarations matching: `function initialize(){}` and `function setupListeners()`.

The object returned simply exposes those 2 functions by returning them to allow calling them as:

```
missileCommand.initialize();
missileCommand.setupListeners();
```

The properties of the returned object could have different names but author wanted the properties to match the function names....the values of the properties are simply *references* to the function object declared previously